# Variables on Magento Terms&Conditions Content

Tags: php, magento

I want to show the recent customer's name, address, telephone details in the Terms & Conditions box of my Magento 2 store's checkout.

Also i need to show cart details.. `product->sku->count->price->discount->total amount`, etc. but first of all, customer details.

I created an HTML content for the Terms & Conditions box in the admin panel. Check here:

[image: Desc]]

Now, how can I add, for example, `Name & Surname: XXX XXX` line in it? Could someone help me?

Comment: Might be better off on https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Updated the question for readability.